# Error with datepicker in angular-formly

Tags: angular-formly

I'm having some problems with datepicker in angular-formly.

This error appears:

> Error: $compile:multidir
>
> Multiple directives [datepickerPopup, uibDatepickerPopup (module: ui.bootstrap.datepicker)] asking for new/isolated on: {5}

Any help?

Comment: please provide more code.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2320